# Uploading a pdf - Tests not being passed when running my POSTMAN tests using newman

Tags: postman, newman, postman-collection-runner

When I run my tests one by one on POSTMAN, it passes

[image]

But Tests not being passed when running my POSTMAN tests using newman.

However, when I try to run it with newman this is the error I get in terminal regarding no pdf file found

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Did You edit path to file inside exported postman collection?

Postman do not save paths to files, and so, every path must be added manually.

You must find body-segment of request and edit filed with key="file":

```
"body": {
        "mode": "formdata",
        "formdata": [
                {
                "key": "file",
                "type": "file",
                "description": "",
                "src": "/mnt/data/www/path_to_file_on_ftp_server/file.pdf"
                }
                    ]
                },
```

You can use full path to ftp location or c: drive.